# how to attach a task to run after the tasks from a plugin in gradle

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, detekt

I have installed the `detekt` plugin in gradle-kotlin with

```
plugins {
  id("io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt").version("1.10.0")
}
```

This yields tasks for me when I run `tasks`:

```
Verification tasks
------------------
check - Runs all checks.
detekt
detektBaseline - Creates a detekt baseline on the given --baseline path.
detektGenerateConfig - Generate a detekt configuration file inside your project.
detektMain - EXPERIMENTAL & SLOW: Run detekt analysis for main classes with type resolution
detektTest - EXPERIMENTAL & SLOW: Run detekt analysis for test classes with type resolution
test - Runs the unit tests.
```

This generates checkstyle xml files. Unfortunately, I am forced to use teamcity, and in order to display the results of detekt in teamcity, it wants all the xml files to be rolled up into a zip file.

So my thought is that for each subproject, I want to run a task that copies the detekt output into a toArchive folder under the subproject's name, and then after detekt has run against ALL subprojects, I want to run the zip task.

The subprojects are each their own top level folder, per [gradle practices](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html):

```
$ tree -L 2
.
├── build
│   └── kotlin
├── build.gradle.kts
├── config
│   └── detekt
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
├── jobs
│   ├── build
│   ├── build.gradle.kts
│   └── src
├── lib
│   ├── build
│   ├── build.gradle.kts
│   └── src
├── README.md
├── settings.gradle.kts
└── SETUP.md
```

But I can't even begin to see how to do this.

I don't really care where the output folder is. I was gonna do the `toArchive` folder at the top level that is in the gradle zip tasks docs. But I don't think it matters much.

I am new to gradle and I find it very confusing.

Comment: It would help if you provide a sample input project directory structure and an expected structure with expected zip file location.

Comment: Ok. I didn't because the locations are arbitrary and knowing where in the build.gradle.kts file to attach the task is all I need. 

But I can anyway. :-)